# Looking for page 98 of TUGboat, volume 5 (1984), No 2

Tags: tugboat, tug

The page 98 of the above mentioned issue of TUGboat is missing from the [tug.org](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb05-2/) archives ([TeXtensions by Jacques Désarménien](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb05-2/tb10desarm.pdf)).
Can I get it somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean the [tug.org](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb05-2/) archive? I don't know if CTAN has these... Very strange, though...

Comment: You are correct, I meant tug.org archive where past issues of TUGboat are stored.

Comment: I retagged your question accordingly.

Comment: i've reported the problem to the tug office.  i'll try to report back when i get an answer; however, i'm in the process of packing up my office at retirement and am short on time to do anything else right now.

Comment: Do not leave us, @barbarabeeton! </3

Comment: For some reason, page 97 appears twice.

Comment: @manooooh -- i won't leave tex.sx.  i'm just retiring from the ams.  i will still be active in tug.

Comment: @egreg -- that should be fixed at the same time.  (haven't heard back yet.)

Answer (score 7):

I've updated https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb05-2/tb10desarm.pdf
and tb10complete.pdf with the real page 98 (scanned by Robin in the TUG office, thanks Robin).